# How to Scroll from top to bottom in react native epub reader in 2023

Tags: react-native, pagination, scrollview, epub.js

In my react native project iam using epub reader package to render epub files. I want to scroll from top to bottom instead of right to left. The package details are
Ebup package
https://github.com/victorsoares96/epubjs-react-native

React native version 0.71.0
"@epubjs-react-native/core": "^1.1.0",
"@epubjs-react-native/file-system": "^1.0.0",

Thanks in advance

I tried to wrap it with scrollview , still didn't work.It has to scroll from top to bottom.